# how to set active in jade engine?

Tags: pug

```
                - var n = 0
                   while n < pages
                      - var num = n + 0;
                      if page == num
                       li.active
                         a(href="?pages=#{n++}")
                           span #{n}
                            span.sr-only (current)
                      else
                       li
                         a(href="?pages=#{n++}")
                           span #{n}
                      - n++
```

The pagination result shows 1 | 3 which is not right. Need to print all number from 1 to page.length. Also the problem is that the specific num is clicked on and then li should be set to active.

Have been trying but couldn't get the result that I hoped for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're incrementing `n` too many times. Either remove the last `n++`, or change `n++` above to just `n`.

```
a(href="?pages=#{n}")
```

Comment: thanks and I overlooked plus plus. I think it is not possible to add active especically when the href will be clicked. so I changed the way thanks